# Change data in an array with N range steps?

Tags: java

Change data in an array with N range steps, for instance, every 2 steps.

int data = new int[8];

```
result:

    [0],[0], [0],[0], [0],[0], [0],[0];
```

expected:
The first two items should change to 1 and the next two will stay in 0 and so on...

```
[1],[1] ,[0],[0], [1],[1], [0],[0];
```

I know the trick with

if(position % 2 == 0)

for changing every 2 items but its changes only the first item.
any idea how to solve it?

```
  int bars =2;
    int beats = 4;
    int[] pattern = new int[bars * beats];
    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
        if(i % bars == 0 ){
            pattern[i] = 0;
        }else{
            pattern[i] = 1;
        }
    }
```

Not the most elegant solution but works
   static int[] data;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int bars = 7;
    int beats = 2;

    data = new int[bars * beats];
    int minVal;

     if(bars > beats){
          minVal = Math.min(bars, beats);
     }else{
          minVal = Math.max(bars, beats);
     }
    step(minVal, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if(i % minVal == 0){
            System.out.print("|"+ data[i]);
        }else{
            System.out.print(data[i]);
        }
    }
}


public static void step(int interval, int value) {
    for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index += interval) {
        for (int stepIndex = index; stepIndex < index + interval; stepIndex++) {
            if (stepIndex > data.length - 1) {
                return;
            }
            data[stepIndex] = value;
        }
        index += interval;
    }
}



   static int[] data;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int bars = 7;
        int beats = 2;

        data = new int[bars * beats];
        int minVal;

         if(bars > beats){
              minVal = Math.min(bars, beats);
         }else{
              minVal = Math.max(bars, beats);
         }
        step(minVal, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(i % minVal == 0){
                System.out.print("|"+ data[i]);
            }else{
                System.out.print(data[i]);
            }
        }
    }


    public static void step(int interval, int value) {
        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index += interval) {
            for (int stepIndex = index; stepIndex < index + interval; stepIndex++) {
                if (stepIndex > data.length - 1) {
                    return;
                }
                data[stepIndex] = value;
            }
            index += interval;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Create a loop on the array length and put the if condition inside the loop to modify all even positions.

Comment: I did but what's the condition?

Comment: Post the code with the lop and we can help :)

Comment: @Jaywalker updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
int bars = 2;
int beats = 4;
int[] pattern = new int[bars * beats];

for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
   if(i % beats < bars ){
      pattern[i] = 1;
   } else {
      pattern[i] = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: There is small problem with your code.. if bars = 4 and beats = 4 the result should be 
    [1],[1],[1],[1], [0],[0],[0],[0], [1],[1],[1],[1], [0],[0],[0],[0];

Comment: yes. it does not work for every array length and step values. It was a solution for the special scenario in your question. anyways hope it was helpful ;)

Comment: thank's, Look at my edited solution. I trying to figure out what if I pass the index manually as a parameter and get the result by the index.

Comment: It's fine, it's still helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is 1 of many ways how you can achieve this. We loop through the array, incrementing by the defined interval, which you want to be 2 for example. We create another for-loop starting at the current index and end at current index + interval which will allow us to assign the value, in your case, 1, to those indices. We also check to see if the current index we're looping through is greater than the data length - 1 to ensure no array index out of bonds for non-even array sizes.

```java
public class ChangeArrayNSteps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChangeArrayNSteps cans = new ChangeArrayNSteps(8);

        cans.step(2, 1);

        System.out.println("Data: " + Arrays.toString(cans.data));
    }

    private final int[] data;

    public ChangeArrayNSteps(int size) {
        this.data = new int[size];
    }

    public void step(int interval, int value) {
        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index += interval) {
            for (int stepIndex = index; stepIndex < index + interval; stepIndex++) {
                if (stepIndex > data.length - 1) {
                    return;
                }
                data[stepIndex] = value;
            }
            index += interval;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:
`Data: [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]`